# Apache spark: map csv file to key: value format

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm totally new to **Apache Spark and Scala**, and I'm having problems with mapping a .csv file into a key-value (like JSON) structure.

What I want to accomplish is to get the .csv file:

```
user, timestamp, event
ec79fcac8c76ebe505b76090f03350a2,2015-03-06 13:52:56,USER_PURCHASED
ad0e431a69cb3b445ddad7bb97f55665,2015-03-06 13:52:57,USER_SHARED
83b2d8a2c549fbab0713765532b63b54,2015-03-06 13:52:57,USER_SUBSCRIBED
ec79fcac8c76ebe505b76090f03350a2,2015-03-06 13:53:01,USER_ADDED_TO_PLAYLIST
...
```

**Into a structure like:**

```
ec79fcac8c76ebe505b76090f03350a2: [(2015-03-06 13:52:56,USER_PURCHASED), (2015-03-06 13:53:01,USER_ADDED_TO_PLAYLIST)]
ad0e431a69cb3b445ddad7bb97f55665: [(2015-03-06 13:52:57,USER_SHARED)]
83b2d8a2c549fbab0713765532b63b54: [(2015-03-06 13:52:57,USER_SUBSCRIBED)]
...
```

How can this be done if the file is read by:

```
val csv = sc.textFile("file.csv")
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: what kind of structure do you need to have as an output?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
     case class MyClass(user: String, date: String, event: String)
     def csvToMyClass(line: String) =
     {
        val split = line.split(',')
        // This is a good place to do validations 
        // And convert strings to numbers, enums, UUIDs, etc.
        MyClass(split(0), split(1), split(2))
     }

     val csv = sc.textFile("file.csv")
        .map(scvToMyClass)
```

Of course, do a little more work to have more concrete data types on your class rather than just strings...

This is for reading the CSV file into a structure (seems to be your main question). If you then need to merge all data for a single user you can map to a key/value tuple `(String -> (String, String))` instead and use `.aggregateByKey()` to join all tuples for a user. Your aggregation function can then return whatever structure you want.

Comment: Ah, and another pointer. If for any reason you want to skip some lines (due to wrong inputs, etc), I usually return an `Option[MyClass]` from the read function and use `flatMap` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is right.

Later you just have to do:

```
csv.keyBy(_.user).groupByKey
```

And that's all.

Comment: That uses the least code indeed. Do note that `aggregateByKey` is potentially much more efficient than `groupByKey` ;-)